# How do I truncate a file X bytes from the end?

Tags: c#, file-io, compact-framework, filestream, truncate

Lets say there is a file which is 150 bytes long and I want to truncate the last 16 (or any number) of it from the end...

Is there any other way to do it than re writing the complete file?

**UPDATE:**
The SetLength should do the thing, but unfortunately NotSupportedException is thrown

```
using (FileStream fsFinalWrite = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{

  fsFinalWrite.Seek(16, SeekOrigin.End);

  fsFinalWrite.Write(SwappedBytes, 0, 16);

  Debug.WriteLine("fsFinalWrite Can Seek = " + fsFinalWrite.CanSeek);
  Debug.WriteLine("fsFinalWrite Can Write = " + fsFinalWrite.CanWrite);

  fsFinalWrite.SetLength((long)lengthOfFile);

}
```

Both print true! But still it throws a NotSupportedException. Anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: operating system? file system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about `FileStream.SetLength()`?

Comment: I was about to add this. Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately there is a `NotSupportedException` thrown when SetLength is used... But i checked, `CanSeek` and `CanRead` are both true... I don't know why it is Not Supported

Comment: Just checked...CanWrite is true as well. Please check the updated question

Comment: For anyone interested, SetLength() is declared as an (abstract) method on the Stream base class, so any other decent Stream sub-classes should, in theory, also provide implementation for truncating its data in this way.  (I am working with MemoryStream and I was curious if the same method would apply).

Answer (score 1):

I am simply using

```
new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
```

instead of

```
new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

and `SetLength` works perfectly, no exception. The file is truncated indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;    
using System.Linq; // as far as you use CF 3.5, it should be available

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
byte[] trancated = bytes.Take(bytes.Lenght - 15);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, trancated);
```

let's encapsulate it a bit:

```
void TruncateEndFile(string path, int size)
{
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, data.Take(data.Lenght - size));
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Although this will work, this will take complete file to memory, change it and then write it back... Isn't there a more efficient way of handling this?

Comment: @Ranhiru: Not the best way, of course. I will think about something more effective